# Update version of child dependency in pom.xml

Tags: java, spring, maven, log4j

In my spring boot application, I'm using `log4j2`.

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-log4j2</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Which is by default picking up version -

```
<version>2.1.6.RELEASE</version>
```

This version of `log4j2` internally uses `log4j`:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
  <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
  <version>2.11.2</version>
  <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
```

Recently it has been announced - log4j has some serious vulnerabilities till version `2.16`.

Also no version of `log4j2` till now uses safer version - `2.17 of log4j`.

So I want to first try to update my pom to use `2.17` version of `log4j` without changing parent `log4j2` version.

I know it might not work & might give compilation issues, but I still want to try it first.

How can I do that?

Comment: First why are you using an old spring boot version?  Furthermore define a new version of log4j-core like 2.17.0

Answer (score 1):

You can use `<dependencyManagement>`:

```xml
<dependencyManagement>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
       <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
       <version>[2.17.0,)</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencyManagement>
```

This configures the dependency `log4j-core` (if it exists) to use version 2.17 or later (see [Version Range References](https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/1212/core/MAVEN/maven_version.htm#MAVEN402)).

Put the `dependencyManagement` section next to your `dependencies` section.

Comment: Do not use version ranges...just write the new version into it...

Comment: the purpose is to force at least that version. If no version was used, maven's version resolution could use an older version. If a version range is used and no resolution is possible, the build will fail (better than a vulnerability).

Comment: The resolution will not use an older version by its own. Only if there is defined one version as directory or transitive dependency. If no version is used/defined at all there will be no resolution of a dependency. This is a misuse of the resolution mechanism If you want to block particular version use Maven Enforcer Plugin with the appropriate enforcer rule...

Comment: Why would it be a misuse of the resolution mechanism? Version ranges exist to specify minimum and maximum versions of dependencies if certain projects need that. Since the project requires that version at minimum to work correctly (without that security issue), this seems like a good option.

Comment: But not to identify dependency requirements...

Comment: How would you define the difference?

Comment: If you like to force to prevent using a particular dependency this should be done via enforcer...

Comment: I want to ensure a minimum version, not enforce a specific one. This is literally the purpose of version ranges.

Comment: This will not even enforce a minimum version...better use enforcer https://maven.apache.org/enforcer/enforcer-rules/bannedDependencies.html

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to define log4j via bom file like this:

```
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>log4j-bom</artifactId>
    <version>2.17.0</version>
    <scope>import</scope>
    <type>pom</type>
  </dependency>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you navigate to parent pom.xml(s), you will see spring-boot-dependencies-2.x.x.pom and find following dependency definition.

```
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>log4j-bom</artifactId>
    <version>${log4j2.version}</version>
    <type>pom</type>
    <scope>import</scope>
  </dependency>
```

So, the version can be overriden and just define your version in your pom.xml as follows.

```
<properties>
  <log4j2.version>2.17.0</log4j2.version>
```

However, this is a specific solution for Log4j2, so I suggest you modify the title putting "Log4j2".